# Streaming a pdf file to the browser from a LotusScript web agent

Tags: pdf, streaming, lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

I'm creating a LotusScript web agent that reads the content of a pdf file somewhere on the network and returns it as a stream to the browser.

the agent will be called like this : `getPDF?openAgent&pdfId=123456` and it should directly returns the pdf stream. (I didn't implement yet the url parameter catching)

Here's my current try, I still have an issue to convert the read buffer to the final stream

```
Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo errrorhandle
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Set stream = session.CreateStream
    Dim buffer As variant
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim txt As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filecontent As String

    filename = "C:\temp\test.PDF"

    If Not stream.Open(filename,"binary") Then
        MessageBox filename,, "Open failed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If stream.Bytes = 0 Then
        MessageBox filename,, "File has no content"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Print "content-type:application/pdf"
    Do
        buffer =  stream.read(1)
        Print buffer(0)
    Loop Until stream.IsEOS

    Call stream.Close

    Exit Sub
errrorhandle :
    Print "Error :" & Error & " at line : " & Erl
    Exit sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh! I break my head on this one... You can't  stream the PDF, but you can copy the file in the \DATA\domino\html of the server and serve it by http://www.myserver.com/copiedPDF.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to output the pdf from a stream in Lotusscript.

I suggest you attach the pdf to a notesdocument and redirect the user to attached file url and later on remove the document.

you can get a hold of the saved pdf using the following syntax
http://server/database/unid/$File/myfile.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Following on [Thomas Adrian response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28645927/5423650), attaching the pdf into a document in a database and then serve the link as described is the best solution.

Keep in mind that this **will require the user to be authenticated**, if said database has or needs restricted access.

If the web users are not authenticated users, you'll need to give at least reader access to "Anonymous" in the ACL of the hosting database for this to work... which is not always advisable if the database has other purposes.

You can however create **a dedicated database** just for this purpose, with unrestricted ACL access.

Comment: technically, I don't understand why I cannot stream a pdf with an agent.

Duplicating the pdf in a Notes database is not an acceptable option for me.

Comment: I've tried your code and apparently it works, however at the end-point the received file is not readable. This has something to do with the way the NotesStream reader works. I've also tried with a simple txt file, and the received content, even though it's "openable", is nowhere near the original content. In addition, the filename proposed by the browser is the same as the agent's name / alias, which in your case would simply be "getPdf", without extension.

Comment: Exactly, so I don't understand what happens, that's the reason of this question ;-)

Comment: I've updated my response above. Sorry. Hit enter prematurely.

Comment: Reviewing your code, I see you left in some unused variables, one of which is "fileNum". I supposed it's a leftover from a previous attempt using the simple `Open filename For Input As fileNum` approach... which must have failed as well.
If the temporary database/document solution is not acceptable, then the last solution would be to use the temporary copy to the `<dominodata>\domino\html` folder as suggested by @Emmanuel Gleizer.
Finally, I'd suggest to include a `Resume` statement in your error handling code, otherwise the error state would not be reset.

Comment: I believe that LS cannot deal with binary zeros in the data, as this is a string terminator. If the PDF data contains binary zeros, the stream fails. In Java, this can be handled ok.