# Lotus Script Web Agent: Send binary data back to browser

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Script Agent that shall return a decoded PDF file (as attachment) that is stored in Notes as a base64 encoded string:

```
Print("Content-type: application/pdf")
Print(DecodeBase64(PDFContentBase64))
```

The issue is that the PDF contains null bytes and the Print statement seems to terminate at the first null byte it encounters. Is there a way to send binary data back to the user's browser from a Lotus Notes Agent?

Comment: Write your agent in Java or see [this entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623796/streaming-a-pdf-file-to-the-browser-from-a-lotusscript-web-agent) or have you tried to send the base64 content as it is ?

Comment: I have tried to send the base64 content as it is, and Chrome says "not a valid PDF document".

Comment: If you need to do it in LotusScript, then one way it works is to write the pdf as an attachment and send the link to it to the browser

Comment: If you want to send it as base64, you're going to need to set a content-transfer-encoding header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an agent print something that should be interpreted by the browser may not be the best course for your intent.

You could attach the PDF to a document then present that document to the user.

Another way, which may or may not be suitable depending on confidentiality concerns and on how cooperative your admin is, would be to save the pdf in the `data/domino/html` directory on the server then pass the corresponding URL to the browser.

Comment: We have chosen exactly that: saved the PDF in the `data/domino/html` directory and send to the browser an http redirect.